# C# winforms save UserID value to class

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

I'm trying to save UserID value to a class after an successful login. When the login button is clicked, it validates the login into in text boxes using the  @user, @pass.

My problem is that I do not know how to write a sql reader and save the resulting int to a class. I also do not know how to write that class.

I need to save it to a class so I can use it on different forms to check what account the user is logged into. 
 EDIT: Updated code from suggestions but i get errors [Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZECq.jpg) any ideas where i did a mistake?

```
private LoginUser validate_login(string user, string pass)
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from table2 where username=@user and password=@pass";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);


        cmd.Connection = connect;
    LoginUser usr = new LoginUser();
    MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     while(login.Read())
     {
             connect.Close();
             usr.UserID = login["UserID"];
             usr.valid = true;
     }    
     return usr;         
}



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            string user = usertype.Text;
            string pass = password.Text;


            if (user == "" || pass == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields Detected ! Please fill up all the fields");
                return;
            }
            bool r = validate_login(user, pass);
            if (r)
            {
                LoginUser usr = new LoginUser();
                usr = validate_login(user, pass);
                if (usr.valid)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", usr.UserID));
                    UserDetails.m_gnUserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create a User class with the properties matching the fields of your table2. In the validate_login create an instance of that class, set its properties using the various reader fields like you do now in the console.writeline. Return the class instance to callers. No need to query two times the database. If the user doesn't exist return a null value. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private LoginUser validate_login(string user, string pass)
    {
         ...
         LoginUser usr = new LoginUser();
         MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();

         while(login.Read())
         {
                 connect.Close();
                 usr.UserID = login["UserID"];
                 usr.valid = true;
         }    
         return usr;         
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        LoginUser usr = new LoginUser();
        usr = validate_login(user, pass);
        if (usr.valid)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", usr.UserID));
        }
    }
}

public class LoginUser
{
    public Bool valid = false;
    public String UserID = "";
    // You can have more column name up to matching with your table column.
}
```

Comment: Anthony i cant implement your code without getting errors could you please share how it should look like implemented with my code. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell what is the error message you received?. The code i show is amendment from the code you have. just replace those "..." to the code you used to have. Because i only show you the concept how you use classes to return a multiple value from function.

Answer (score 0):

One of the method is as follow

1. Create a class `UserDetails` with all the data you want to store

   ```
   public static class UserDetails
   {
       public static int m_gnUserId {get;set;} 
       //Add other variables which you want to store and use across different forms
   }
   ```
2. To Store Value 
   `UserDetails.m_gnUserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]);` .

This storing of Value will go after `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["UserID"]));` in your `button1_click` event.

3. To get the value on other form 
   `int UserId = UserDetails.m_gnUserId;`

Comment: Im trying to implement your method but im having problems. Ive uploaded pic of errors. Could you please jump over i cant seem to find it. Thanks

Comment: replace `usr.UserID` instead of `reader["UserID"]` in storing value